# QVariant to QDBusArgument

Tags: c++, qt, dbus

I have a problem with the DBUS in QT 5.7.

I receive a variant, and inside that variant I know there is a `QVariantMap` (i.e. a `QMap` if `QVariant`s indexed by `strings`).

What I receive in the message is the `QVariant` object. I know that inside it there is a QDBusArgument (the debugger says so, see attached image), but I don't know what is the proper way to extract it nor the QVariantMap.

As for now, what I did is

```
QDBusArgument *darg = static_cast<QDBusArgument*>((void *)vm.data());
QVariantMap elems;
*darg >> elems;
```

but I'm not sure about that approach, nor I like the static cast. Is there any alternative?

Best regards

[image: What the debugger say]

EDIT:

After one comment, I was able to write a "nicer" version, qith `qdbus_cast`:

```
QVariantMap elems = qdbus_cast<QVariantMap>(*(static_cast<QDBusArgument*>((void *)vm.data())));
```

This, however, does not answer my question, since the most important part was about the `static_cast` (and if there was a way to avoid it, since it is insecure).

Answer (score 2):

To improve the casting

```
QVariantMap elems = qdbus_cast<QVariantMap>(*(static_cast<QDBusArgument*>((void *)vm.data())));
```

we could use the `value<T>()` (or `qvariant_cast`)

```
QVariantMap elems = qdbus_cast<QVariantMap>( vm.value<QDBusArgument>() );
```

Answer (score 1):

QVariant class has a method for this, see [toMap()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#toMap).

And just as documentation says, see also [canConvert()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#canConvert-1) and [convert()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#convert).

Comment: Already tried. As the documentation say, the toMap method works "if the variant has type() QMetaType::QVariantMap". This QVariant has a type wit id 1024 (i.e. a user type, since i is a QDBusArgument), so I can't extract it with this method (in fact, it returns an empty map). The convert function is used (if I'm right) to cast one type to another, but I can't extract it..

Comment: I didn't get what you meant by `I receive a variant, and inside that variant I know there is a QVariantMap` then. How it comes that it has user type?

Comment: Sorry, the rest of the post should have explained it better. As I wrote later the `QVariant` IS a `QDbusArgument`, and INSIDE it there is a `QVariantMap`. This is why I had to cast the inner data to `QDBusArgument`, and then extract the map. The function `toMap` implies the `QVariant` IS a `QVariantMap`

Comment: Then you need to use http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdbusargument.html#qdbus_cast i think.

Comment: I added the qdbus implementation; anyway that cast is for the second part of the code, which was already "safe"; the static_cast part has to be kept the same way. Is there a way to avoid it?